# Oracle managed data access: throws not enough values c#

Tags: c#, oracle11g

Though I found many answers to the same question but non of those solved my problem, so I'm posting this question. I am getting `not enough values` exception while trying to insert data to Oracle DB using `Oracle.ManagedDataAccess` in c#.

Below my code

```
string cmdQuery = string.Format("INSERT INTO HKSTF087.FREIGHTCHARGES" +
"(QTM_ID,TITLECODE,SERVICETYPE,FREIGHTCHARGERATE,FREIGHTCHARGETYPE,FREIGHTCHARGETARRIFCODE," +
"ORIGINID,FREIGHTCALCULATIONTYPE,EFFECTIVEFROMDATE,EFFECTIVETHRUDATE,CREATEDBY,CREATEDDATETIME,UPDATEDBY,UPDATEDDATETIME)" +
"VALUES(:QTM_ID,:TITLECODE,:SERVICETYPE,:FREIGHTCHARGERATE,:FREIGHTCHARGETYPE,:FREIGHTCHARGETARRIFCODE" +
":ORIGINID,:FREIGHTCALCULATIONTYPE,:EFFECTIVEFROMDATE,:EFFECTIVETHRUDATE,:CREATEDBY,:CREATEDDATETIME,:UPDATEDBY,:UPDATEDDATETIME)");

OracleParameter[] parameters = new OracleParameter[]
{
    new OracleParameter("QTM_ID",OracleDbType.Int32,origin.OriginId, ParameterDirection.Input),
    new OracleParameter("TITLECODE", OracleDbType.Varchar2, origin.TitleCode.Trim(), ParameterDirection.Input ),
    new OracleParameter("SERVICETYPE", OracleDbType.Varchar2, origin.ServiceType.Trim(), ParameterDirection.Input ),
    new OracleParameter("FREIGHTCHARGERATE", OracleDbType.Decimal, origin.FreightChargeRate, ParameterDirection.Input ),
    new OracleParameter("FREIGHTCHARGETYPE", OracleDbType.Varchar2, origin.FreightChargeRateType, ParameterDirection.Input ),
    new OracleParameter("FREIGHTCHARGETARRIFCODE", OracleDbType.Varchar2, origin.FreightChargeTariffCode, ParameterDirection.Input ),
    new OracleParameter("ORIGINID", OracleDbType.Varchar2, origin.OriginId.ToString(), ParameterDirection.Input ),
    new OracleParameter("FREIGHTCALCULATIONTYPE", OracleDbType.Varchar2, origin.FreightCalculationType, ParameterDirection.Input ),
    new OracleParameter("EFFECTIVEFROMDATE", OracleDbType.Date, effectiveFromDate, ParameterDirection.Input ),
    new OracleParameter("EFFECTIVETHRUDATE", OracleDbType.Date, "12/31/2099", ParameterDirection.Input ),
    new OracleParameter("CREATEDBY", OracleDbType.Varchar2, "system", ParameterDirection.Input ),
    new OracleParameter("CREATEDDATETIME", OracleDbType.Date, createdDate, ParameterDirection.Input ),
    new OracleParameter("UPDATEDBY", OracleDbType.Varchar2, null, ParameterDirection.Input ),
    new OracleParameter("UPDATEDDATETIME", OracleDbType.Date, null, ParameterDirection.Input )
};
//other code 
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

`cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();` throws exception `ORA-00947: not enough values` but As far I can see all parameter are just fine and perhaps I'm not able to see the cause of the problem. I also have done similar thing with another table and that does inserts data to the table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
"VALUES(:QTM_ID,:TITLECODE,:SERVICETYPE,:FREIGHTCHARGERATE,:FREIGHTCHARGETYPE,:FREIGHTCHARGETARRIFCODE" +
":ORIGINID,:FREIGHTCALCULATIONTYPE,:EFFECTIVEFROMDATE,:EFFECTIVETHRUDATE,:CREATEDBY,:CREATEDDATETIME,:UPDATEDBY,:UPDATEDDATETIME)");
```

I'm noticing the lack of a comma after 'FREIGHTCHARGETARRIFCODE', that might do it on oracle.

Also, it's been a little while since I've used ODP, but I think the use of `null` instead of `DbNull.Value` could be tripping it up and trimming those parameters instead of including them. (Edit: Also the tossing of a string for the oracle date may or may not be an issue.)

All of this is also assuming that you're adding the parameters to the command in the elided code.